# Module can use view class contained in another module without depending on it. How?

Tags: android, gradle, multi-module, gradle-dependencies

I have a multimodule android project and the setup is the following:

There is a `customviews` module which contains the `CustomLayout` class (which extends from `FrameLayout`).
Then, there is a `feature` module which uses the `CustomLayout` in one of it's layouts.

Here is the kicker: `feature` module does *not* depend on `customviews` module but the project builds and runs successfully!

When navigating to the `CustomLayout` usage in `feature` module, android studio marks it "red" and cannot find the class declaration. Note: There are no "api" transitive dependencies of `customviews`

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have nested dependencies? for example if A implemented B and B is implemented C, then A can use all C functionalities.

Comment: It's not about classes, it's about gradle modules. As far as I am aware `implementation` hides the dependency, `api` exposes it